# Joint probability distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are jointly distributed with density $f(y_1,y_2)=4y_2^2 \qquad 0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2 \leq 1$

Determine the following:

$P(\text{max} \{Y_1,Y_2\} <1/2) = \int_{y_2=0}^{1/2}\int_{y_1=0}^{y_2}4y_2^2dy_1dy_2  \approx 0.0625$ 
$P(Y_1+Y_2 < 1/2) = \int_{y_1=0}^{1/4}\int^{1/2-y_1}_{y_2=y_1}4y_2^2dy_2dy_1 \approx 0.0182292$ 
$P(Y_1Y_2 <1/2) = \int_{y_2=0}^{\sqrt{1/2}}\int_{y_1=0}^{y_2}4y_2^2dy_1dy_2 + \int_{y_2=\sqrt{1/2}}^{1}\int_{y_1=0}^{1/(2y_2)}4y_2^2dy_1dy_2 = 1/4 + 1/2 = 0.75$ 
$P(Y_1/Y_2<1/2) = \int_{y_2=0}^{1}\int_{y_1=(1/2)y_2}^{y_2}4y_2^2dy_1dy_2 = 0.5$ 
$P(Y_2-Y_1 < 1/2) = \int_{y_2=0}^{1/2}\int_{y_1=0}^{y_2}4y^2_2dy_1dy_2 + \int_{y_2=1/2}^{1}\int_{y_1=y_2-(1/2)}^{y_2}4y^2_2dy_1dy_2 \approx 0.583333+0.0625 = 0.645833$ 
$P(\text{min} \{Y_1,Y_2\}<1/2) = \int_{y_2=1/2}^{1}\int_{dy_1=0}^{y_2}4y^2_2dy_1dy_2 \approx 0.9375 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do the first problem, since that is the one you attacked in some detail.   Subscripts are a pain to type. Also, the geometry of the $x$-$y$ plane is familiar. So we use $x$ instead of $y_1$ and $y$ instead of $y_2$, though reversing the choices would be better.
And we call the random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Our density function is then $4y^2$, and lives on $0\le x\le y\le 1$. This region is a triangle with corners $(0,0))$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. Draw the triangle. The boundary line $y=x$ will be important.

We want the probability that $X\lt 1/2$ and $Y\lt 1/2$. This is the integral of the joint density function over the part of our triangle that is inside the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1/2,0)$, $(1/2,1/2)$ and $(0,1/2)$.

Draw the region over which we need to integrate. It is a triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1/2,1/2)$, and $(0,1/2)$.

Now we are finished. It is a matter of taste whether we integrate first with respect to $x$ or with respect to $y$. Let's do $x$ first. We want
$$\int_{y=0}^{1/2}\left(\int_{x=0}^y 4y^2\,dx                  \right)\,dy.$$

The others are quite similar, mostly a little harder. In all cases the only real work is to carefully identify the region over which we are integrating. That is why we deliberately spent so much time focusing on the geometry. Sometimes it is convenient to find first the probability of the complement.

For example, for $X+Y\lt 1/2$ we will draw our basic triangle again, and draw the line $x+y=1/2$. In this case it will be convenient to integrate first with respect to $y$.

If one of the problems causes difficulty, please leave a comment.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where this "triangle" comes from considering you are only using the function $f(y)=4y^2$

Comment: The expression $4^2$ is of minor importance.  We are told that our function is $4y^2$ **when** $0\le x\le y\le 1$.  **That restriction** is the key, for it implicitly says that the joint density $f(x,y)$ is $0$ elsewhere. They should have said so explicitly.  The density function is $0$ outside the triangle we are discussing, so all integrations that mention $4y^2$ are restricted to that triangle or a subset of it. That will be the case for every one of the parts of the problem.

Comment: i made a better attempt at the problems. yet im still confused as to why some of the integrals do not converge

Comment: There should be no convergence issue in any of these. The second problem is $\int_{x=0}^{1/4} \int_{y=x}^{1/2-x}4y^2\,dy\,dx$.

Comment: All the other setups are wrong. Every region of integration must be a subset of the basic triangle I identified in the answer, where the joint density "lives." If you have a specific other question among the several, I can set up the integral for you in an addition to my answer. Only one, please say chosen from 3 to 6. It may take a few hours, I will be away part of today.

Comment: @JonathanMckibbin: In case you did not get the previous comment, I can do another part of your choice.

Comment: I think I got it. I will repost my new answers this time but I'm fairly certain they are correct.

Comment: They are now posted!

Comment: Going out, do not have time to verify any. If there is **one** you have doubt about, I can verify. For the second, the setup is now right. A scan shows the others have not obviously unreasonable shape, but that does not mean right. I am a bit dubious about the last.

Comment: The minimum question, I believe I am wrong but I would like to give it another try before I see the solution.